# Script to end process with a specific name

Tags: scripting, windows-xp

I have to kill two processes with the same image name (system and my local user name) every day. Is there a script that I could write or do I have to go to the task manager every time windows starts up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taskkill is the command you're looking for. It can even take pretty specific filtering arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A bat file would do it, and could say

`taskkill /im regedit.exe`

(taskkill /? has other examples)

a vbs file with this line does it too

`CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "taskkill /im regedit.exe", 0, False`

more invisibly done than just having windows just normally running a batch file